# How to include the code into a REPLACE function in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, ascii, non-ascii-characters

User @psaraj12 helped me with a ticket here about finding ascii character in a string in my DB with the following code:

```
with test (col) as (
  select 
    'L.A.D' 
  from 
    dual 
  union all 
  select 
    'L..D.' 
  from 
    dual
) 
select 
  col, 
  case when max(ascii_of_one_character) >= 65535 then 'NOT OK' else 'OK' end result 
from 
  (
    select 
      col, 
      substr(col, column_value, 1) one_character, 
      ascii(
        substr(col, column_value, 1)
      ) ascii_of_one_character 
    from 
      test cross 
      join table(
        cast(
          multiset(
            select 
              level 
            from 
              dual connect by level <= length(col)
          ) as sys.odcinumberlist
        )
      )
  ) 
group by 
  col
  having max(ascii_of_one_character) >= 4000000000;
```

The script looks for characters of a certain range `GROUP`s them and marks displays them.

Is it possible to include this in a REPLACE statement of a similar sort:

```
REPLACE(table.column, max(ascii_of_one_character) >= 4000000000, '')
```

EDIT: As per @flyaround answer this is the code I use changed a little bit:

```
with test (col) as (
  select skunden.name1
  from skunden
) 
select col
 , REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'max(ascii_of_one_character)>=4000000000', '') as cleaned
 , CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(col, 'max(ascii_of_one_character)>=4000000000') > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as isOk 
from test;
```

Comment: What is your intended result for the Replace? What value should your example values ('L..D.', 'L.A.D') from above have as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to your original code, because my suggested REGEX_REPLACE is not working sufficient with high surrogates. Your approach is already very effective, so I jumped into it to have a solution here.

```
MERGE
INTO  skunden   
USING (

  select 
    id as innerId, 
    name as innerName, 
    case when max(ascii_of_one_character) >= 65535 then 0 else 1 end isOk, 
    listagg(case when ascii_of_one_character <65535 then one_character end , '') within group (order by rn) as cleaned  
  from 
    (
      select
        id,
        name, 
        substr(name, column_value, 1) one_character, 
        ascii(
          substr(name, column_value, 1)
        ) ascii_of_one_character 
        , rownum as rn
      from 
        skunden cross 
        join table(
          cast(
            multiset(
              select 
                level 
              from 
                dual connect by level <= length(name)
            ) as sys.odcinumberlist
          )
        )
    ) 
  group by 
    id, name 
    having max(ascii_of_one_character) >= 4000000000

)
ON (skunden.id = innerId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET name = cleaned
;
```

On MERGE you can't use the referencing column for an update. Therefore you should use the unique key (I used 'id' in my example) of your table.

The resulting value will be 'L..D' for your example value of 'L..D.'

Comment: Thank you for this! I will have a look and test as soon as possible and comment with the results.

Comment: It is perfect. It works great. I thought I wrote, but apparently not. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly you would like to remove characters with a higher decimal representation of characters than specified.
You could check to use REGEXP_REPLACE for this, like:

```
with test (col) as (
  select 
    'L.A.D' 
  from 
    dual 
  union all 
  select 
    'L..D.' 
  from 
    dual
) 
select col
 , REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[^\u00010000-\u0010FFFF]+$', '') as cleaned 
 , CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(col, '[^\u00010000-\u0010FFFF]+$') > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as isOk 
from test;
```

Comment: Awesome. This works amazing replacing the symbols on display. Is it possible to incorporate this into an UPDATE, or change the data itself underneath the display only? I put an EDIT on my question to include the whole code you provided with little changes, which we needed to do.

Comment: I would make such changes with a MERGE statement. But unfortunately I encountered potential limitations of Oracle's REGEX_REPLACE function with high surrogates. Please have a look on @vincent-malgrat answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381686/high-surrogate-detection-in-oracle-regular-expression

Comment: @DarkBlade: I don't think that the added code to your question will work. The REGEX_REPLACE function needs a regular expression. See documentation on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Comment: I see. But would there be another way we can do that? Even if it is not with `regexp_replace()` it would greatly help if we have a script that looks for characters with ascii above a certain number and replaces them with ''.  `replace` in this case would net be helpful as we need to change the data in the DB, not just the displayed string.

Comment: Hi @flyaround, I can swear this script (and the one in my Edit which was changed) worked 2 days ago. Now when I run it it does not clean the symbols for some reason. Do you have an idea why this might be?